# Making data joined from Excel independent in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, csv, attribute-joins, excel

I have joined some data from Excel (.csv) "text" to my attributes table of one feature class. However I can't edit it. I found out it is still connected to Excel file from where I added it, and I need to edit changes in original Excel file to make them appear in ArcMap 10.2.

I'd like to know, how can I break the link from the original file and make the data appear independently in a 'field' inside the feature class.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve a permanent copy of the fields that you have joined to a feature class, you need to export it to a new feature class. Right-click the layer in the TOC and choose Data > Export Data.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to exporting the results of a join is to use the [Join Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000065000000) tool instead of creating a join. This tool directly adds the attributes to the feature class based on a join (one step) as opposed to joining and exporting (two step).